# Flex Skins

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, skinning

We need to create Adobe Air application in quick time with lot of emphasis on cool UI effects. We thought of using UI components, skins by a third party due to time limitations. Can anyone direct me to good places. I've only found [ScaleNine](http://www.scalenine.com/gallery/index.php) which is close to our expected standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/examples/WedgeStackChartExample.html) and [Birdeye](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ng/examples/demo/BirdEyeExplorer.html) which have cool effects.  And [Openflux](http://tarasnovak.com/lab/Random3DView/Random3DView.html) has some cool effects.

Here's a good skin, not made in Flex but it's nice: [GUIFX](http://www.guifx.com/_product_63731/Dean)

And Tink's made a nice Flex Effect library called [Efflex](http://www.efflex.org/EfflexExplorer.html).

Scalenine's the best I've seen so far.

Oh and there's [FlashDen](http://flashden.net/) and other Envato sites.

Hope that helps.